# Redirect from one page to another in Laravel based off of ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is not working in my Laravel. I want to make each list able to be redirected to another page using the ID.

`viewps.blade.php`:

```
@foreach ($ps as $ps )
    <li>{{HTML::link_to_route('viewps',$ps->name,array($ps>id ))}}
    <li>{{ $ps->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/viewps', 'PsController@show');
Route::get('/viewps/{id}', 'PsController@view')->name('viewps');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

`pscontroller`:

```
public function show()
{
    $ps = DB::table('ps')->get();
    return view('viewps', ['ps' => $ps]);
}

public function view($id)
{
    $ps = Ps::find($id);

    // show the view and pass to it
    return view ('view')->with('ps', $ps);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line :

```
{{HTML::link_to_route('viewps',$ps->name,array($ps>id ))}}
```

to:

```
<a href="{{ route('viewps', $ps->id) }}">{{ $ps->name }}</a>
```

Comment: it will just echo out the whole url of the route

Comment: sorry my bad, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the html/form helper of the Laravel. I ussually do something like this

Revise your html like this :

```
@foreach ($ps as $ps )  
   <a href="{{ route('viewps', [ 'id' => $ps->id] ) }}">{{ $ps->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```